# How to make my website remember user/password logins

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, remember-me, dotnetnuke-7

I'm running my website under DotNetNuke version 07.00.02 and it does not remember user/password on client's logins.
Can someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Remember me functionality? Sessions and cookies surely. I hope you're not storing your passwords in plain text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `PersistentCookieTimeout` in `web.config` to some value which is greater than `0`, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="2016000" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Also make sure that cookies are enabled and users do not use the `incognito` mode.

Related: [`PersistentCookieTimeout`](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/persistentcookietimeout) and [Why doesn't "Remember me" work like I expect?](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134982/why-doesnt-remember-me-work-like-i-expect)

Comment: Where is this cookie supposed to be nested?  I just tried to nest it under 

<authentication mode="Forms">

And it was not recognized.

Comment: This should be added as `<appSettings>` child.